# Array causing my program to crash

Tags: java, android, arrays, date, calendar

I'm trying to make an app that checks the day of the year.  Whenever I declare an array larger than a certain number, I get a Stops responding message.  What should i do?

```
 public class Main extends Activity {

int[] payDays = new int[11];
int dayOfYear;
Calendar cal;

Intent goToSales, goToChains, goToCheck, goToReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    dayOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    payDays = new int[11];

    payDays[0] = 60;
    payDays[1] = 88;
    payDays[2] = 123;
    payDays[3] = 151;
    payDays[4] = 179;
    payDays[5] = 214;
    payDays[6] = 242;
    payDays[7] = 270;
    payDays[8] = 305;
    payDays[9] = 333;
    payDays[10] = 361;
    payDays[11] = 31;

    // Phew! Checks when to send the notification
    if (dayOfYear == payDays[0] || 
        dayOfYear == payDays[1] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[2] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[3] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[4] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[5] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[6] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[7] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[8] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[9] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[10] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[11]) 
    {


        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("MCHelper")
        .setContentText("It's the end of the year!")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify2).build();
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


        NotificationManager notiMan = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          notiMan.notify(0, noti);

          Context context = getApplicationContext();
          CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
          int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
          toast.show();   
    }
```

Comment: Wow, the if logical expression is truly UGLY, with full caps. Why not just do this? `boolean dayOk=false; for(int i=0;i<12;i==) { if(dayOfYear == payDays[i]) { dayOk=true; break; } }` Or even better: extract this shorter code to be a function: `private final boolean isItOkToSend(int dayOfYear, int[] payDays) { for(int i=0;i<12;i++) { if(dayOfYear == payDays[i]) { return true; } } return false; }` Also a shorter form of initializing an array with content is: `int[] payDays={60,88,123,151,179,214,242,270,305,333,361,31};`

Answer (score 4):

Look at this:

```
int[] payDays = new int[11];
```

Now you're trying to access index 11:

```
payDays[11] = 31;
```

That's not going to work. When you use `new int[size]` (or any other type of array, of course) that create an array with `size` elements, from 0 inclusive to `size` **exclusive**.

I suspect you want:

```
int[] payDays = new int[12];
```

(Additionally, I'd either use a loop to check whether the array contains a particular value, or change the ordering so that it's in order, and use `Arrays.binarySearch`.)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your array wrong. Instead of `payDays = new int[11];` you want `payDays = new int[12];` Otherwise, you end up accessing element 11, which is out of bounds and you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

The array index starts from zero.As you declare an array of size eleven,**an array elements of index ranging from 0 to 10(total 11 elements)** will be created.Hence  accessing payDays[11] would throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception.

The solution could be

> 1)Increase the size of the array as **payDays = new int[12]**;
>
> 2)Remove the element payDays[11] = 31;